# Is there a way to avoid inadvertently passing a non-boolean argument to a boolean parameter?

Tags: c++

I got bit by a C++ type-safety issue today, and I'm wondering if there is a good way to get the compiler to detect this issue at compile time.  Consider this example code:

```
class Bar
{
public:
   void Foo(bool arg1 = false, int arg2 = 10, int arg3 = 20)
   {
      [...]
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int x = 40, y = 50;
   Bar b;
   b.Foo();            // correct usage
   b.Foo(true, x, y);  // correct usage
   b.Foo(x, y);        // problem:  compiles but won't do what the caller expects
}
```

As shown in the final call to b.Foo(), the issue is that it's easy to forget to supply the first argument, and in that case things go wrong in a way that is not caught by the compiler.

What would be nice is if I could get the compiler to say something like "ERROR, non-boolean value was supplied to a boolean parameter".  That would force the developer to examine the code, and if he really wanted to pass in x as a boolean, he'd have to pass in (x!=0) instead.

This seems like a good place to use the "explicit" keyword, but AFAICT that keyword doesn't work for function arguments.

(I realize that this sort of issue could be avoided by not supplying default values for the arguments, but default values can be quite handy)

Comment: Easy answer: avoid Boolean parameters in general.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin What would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Perhaps one could exploit the overload rules and provide a function with 2 args explicitly. But I find your question interesting. It would be nice to have an "explicit" qualifier for parameters.

Comment: I'd usually prefer an enumeration, so at the very least the parameters say what they really mean.

Comment: @PeterSchneider `Explicit<bool>` is pretty close to `explicit bool`, wouldn't you agree? ^^

Comment: Quite surprised [you don't get a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fb863be80cbf4a4), frankly. Narrowing conversions and all that.

Comment: I think, in real live, it doesn't happen often that arg2 and arg3 (x and y) have a default value. and without a default value for these args you don't get into this problem. otherwise use overloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function overloading can catch that

```
public: void Foo(bool arg1 = false, int arg2 = 10, int arg3 = 20);

private: void Foo(int&, ...); // can't omit leading arguments, dummy!
```

Or in C++11 and later, use `= delete` (some so-called C++11 compilers don't support this yet, though)

Answer (score 7):

You may provide deleted overloads:

```
class Bar
{
public:
   void Foo(bool arg1 = false, int arg2 = 10, int arg3 = 20)
   {
      [...]
   }

    template <typename T>
    void Foo(T&&, int = 10, int = 20) = delete;
};
```

As the template method would be an exact match for non bool parameter.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: if first argument is not a bool, the template method would be chosen. As it is deleted, you got a compiler error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Can be changed to works with C++03: `private` instead of `=delete`, `const T&` instead of `T&&`.

Answer (score 4):

As you noted `explicit bool` does not work in this context - but we can instead manage to make `Explicit<bool>` work, which looks almost exactly the same.

First, a bit of [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) trait magic helps provide a class which has a constructor that only works for real `bool`s:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename U>
struct Explicit
{
    bool value;
    template<typename T = U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, U>::value>>
    Explicit(T&& value) : value(value) { }
    operator U() { return value; }
};
```

With this helper available you can simply say:

```
void Foo(Explicit<bool> arg1 = false, int arg2 = 10, int arg3 = 20) { }
```

See the [success](https://ideone.com/r66aBZ) and the [failure](https://ideone.com/3CJvqt) and pay special attention to the error message:

> prog.cpp:22:11: error: could not convert 'x' from 'int' to 'Explicit<bool>'

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this trick with a template:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T param);

template <>
void foo<bool>(bool param)
{

}


foo(true); // OK
foo(9); // Won't c̶o̶m̶p̶i̶l̶e̶  link
```